# Java Script user defined functions are not working in windows 7 phone gap

Tags: windows, cordova

I have created windows phone gap application. In that it internally uses browser called mypgview . I have created JavaScript function in index.html page but it is not working properly. I have written html5 code.

Can any one resolve my problem?

Comment: Please post some code. Ideally your whole page but if that's not possible, the <head> part of your document, with your JavaScript. If you don't it's going to be hard for us to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i called alert function directly .It's not working while i call it directly ,then i changed like this navigator.notification.alert("Hi"); now it is working.
Thank You